# why is this.state.records.amount undefined?

Tags: reactjs

I am in the process of learning React and having some trouble with my state. I am trying to get a function to log `this.state.records.amount` to my console when the component is rendered but it shows up as undefined. If someone can figure this out it would be VERY much appreciated.

Records component:

```
class Records extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        records: []
    }

    this.handleNewRecord = this.handleNewRecord.bind(this);
    this.handleDeleteRecord = this.handleDeleteRecord.bind(this);
    this.surplus = this.surplus.bind(this);
    this.debt = this.debt.bind(this);
    this.total = this.total.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        records: this.props.records
    })
}

 handleNewRecord(record) { 
     let records = this.state.records.slice();
     records.push(record)
     this.setState({
         records: records
     })
}

handleDeleteRecord(record) {
    let records = this.state.records.slice();
    let index = records.indexOf(record)
    records.splice(index, 1)
    this.setState({
        records: records
    })
}

surplus() {
    console.log(this.state.records[0].amount)
    }

debt() {
    console.log("debt")
}

total() {
    console.log("total")
}


render() { 
    const records = this.state.records.map((record) =>
        <Record record={record} key={record.id}  handleDeleteRecord={this.handleDeleteRecord}/>
    )
    return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Records</h1>
                <div className="row">
                    <AmountBox panelClass="panel panel-primary" panelHeader="Surplus" calculatedAmount={this.surplus()} />
                    <AmountBox panelClass="panel panel-warning" panelHeader="Debt" calculatedAmount={this.debt()} />
                    <AmountBox panelClass="panel panel-success" panelHeader="Total" calculatedAmount={this.total()} />
                </div>
             <RecordForm handleNewRecord={this.handleNewRecord}/>
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {records}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )   
}     
}
```

Amount Box component:

```
class AmountBox extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
}

render () {
  return (
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <div className={this.props.panelClass}>
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h3 className="panel-title">{this.props.panelHeader}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <p>
                            {this.props.calculatedAmount}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>          
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.state.records[0].amount` is `undefined` because on first render you are setting `records` to `[]` (in the constructor).

`setState` will trigger a second render, but in the first render the changes to `state` by `setState` will not apply.

So, you need some defensive code that makes sure that `this.state.records` have items.

```
surplus() {
    this.state.records.length ? this.state.records[0].amount : 0;
}
```

Comment: or use something like lodash `_.get` method so you dont always have to check an entire path every time :)

Comment: what if I wanted to log all the amounts? as soon as I remove `[0]` I get undefined again

Comment: It is an array, correct?  So, you'll have to `map` through the values

Comment: Okay, I understand. But this is still going to come up undefined without the defensive code? what I really want to put in the function is something like

Comment: 'surplus() {
  var surplus = this.state.records.filter((value) => 
    value.amount >= 0
   )
  surplus.reduce((total, amount) total + amount)
  }'